# D3 - unable to access d.length in IF statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I've been trying to put my head around this one, but I really can't figure it out - nor find anything on the web regarding this. Althought I'm new to D3, I once used to be a developper ;)

I'm simply trying to access d.length using an IF statement.

The fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/StephMatte/yA6ma/

On line 24, I want to use (d.length < 2) but it breaks up the rest of the script, probably returning "undefined" or something like that.

But, on line 27 I do make use of d.length in an onclick alert statement and it does give the right result! Here's the full code :

```
var data = []; var base = 9; var div = "#chart";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 11*base; i++) {data[i] = [23, 45, 67, 89];}

    var Angle = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2 * Math.PI]); 

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius( function(d, i) {return 20*(Math.ceil(i/base));} )
        .outerRadius( function(d, i) {return 20+(20*(Math.ceil(i/base)));} )
        .startAngle( function(d, i) {return Angle((((i-1)%base)/base)*100); } )
        .endAngle( function(d, i) { if (Angle(((i%base)/base)*100) == 0) { return Angle(100); } else { return Angle(((i%base)/base)*100); }  } );

    var paths = d3.select(div)
        .append("svg")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) {return "path"+i})
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { if (1 > 2 || i <= base) { return "blue"; } else { return "red"; } })
        .style("stroke", function(d, i) { if (i <= base) { return "transparent"; } else { return "#fff"; } })
        .attr("transform", "translate(250,250)")
        .on("click", function(d, i) { alert(d.length); });
```

I tried just about everything : passing the value into a variable before the IF and using that, parseInt(d.length) just in case, tried boldly nesting another function/return(d.length) but to no avail.

Is this a bug of some sort or is there something that really, really passed me by??

Any input would be appreciated!

P.-S. Yes, the data is dummy and normally my data array is filled with arrays of different lengths hence the condition for coloring. In the example, I just simplified to illustrate the behavior.

Comment: Start with index 0 on `for (var i = 1;...`, so `for (var i = 0;...`. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nivaldo/yA6ma/2/) with the change you want. (You were getting undefined before because there was no data for d[0].)

Comment: Aaaah! Yes, of course. I actually do not intend to use index 0, so I completely just... well, forgot about it. I'll just add a dummy value into it so it doesn't break up the code again. Many, many thanx!

Comment: YMW...one of these small things that can bite us :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been bitten a lot since I undertook this project and will probably be back with some "small things" here and there. BTW, I'm kind of new here (my username and "reputation" say so) and I was wondering : how do I flag you as being my savior of the day?

Comment: I will post this as the solution to your answer and you can accept it. That would be an official way to recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with index 0 on `for (var i = 1;...`, so `for (var i = 0;....`.

(You were getting undefined before because there was no data for d[0].)

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gB8sp/) with the change you want.